# Problem in seeking video in C# using vlc player

Tags: c#, video, activex, vlc

I am using the following code to jump to a particular time location in the video

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var replay = new Uri(@"Test.wmv");
    var converted_url = replay.AbsoluteUri;
    axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(converted_url);
    axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
    axVLCPlugin21.input.time = 10000; // Jump to 10th second
}
```

Which works fine. But when the video is being written simultaneously while being displayed the code doesn't work and the video starts from zeroth second without throwing an error. Can someone suggest what's wrong or how to debug the code?

Comment: DO NOT use the AxVLCPlugin. It is unmaintained and unsupported. Use a supported wrapper, like Vlc.DotNet or LibVLCSharp.

Comment: @mtz I tried to read documentation of Vlc.DotNet , which seems rather confusing, how can i embed vlc player in my form?

Comment: What do you call "form"?

Comment: The GUI, where I can add the player, buttons etc

Comment: Try the samples in the vlc.dotnet repository

Comment: @mtz I tried "vlcControl1.Play(@"c:\Media1.mp4"); " but the video is not playing. With the errors  "mmdevice audio output error: cannot initialize COM (error 0x80010106)
main input error: Your input can't be opened"

Comment: Create an issue on the repo then. It's offtopic from initial question now.